# Drown dashed lines on swift getting weird

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-graphics, quartz-core

I'm trying to draw some dashed lines in an UIView but I don't know if I'm doing it right. The first dash has half width compared to the others.

Code:

```
    let strokeColor                      = UIColor.white.cgColor
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path2.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50)) 
    path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 340, y: 50))

    //thickHorizontalLayer.frame         = frame
    thickHorizontalLayer.path            = path.cgPath
    thickHorizontalLayer.strokeColor     = strokeColor
    thickHorizontalLayer.lineWidth       = 15
    thickHorizontalLayer.fillColor       = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    thickHorizontalLayer.lineDashPattern = [ 0.5, 6 ]
    thickHorizontalLayer.lineDashPhase   = 0.25

    self.layer.addSublayer(thickHorizontalLayer)
```

Look what it draws: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UTdj.jpg

Is this the best way to do it?
If you see, the first dash is thiner than others...

plus question: how I can get the y value of the UIView's bound? e.g. bound=340, is this case above.

EDIT:

I'm Trying to draw 2 dash patterns (One thin and other thick) but it's getting confusing...:

```
    fileprivate let thickHorizontalLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    fileprivate let thinHorizontalLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    let strokeColor                      = UIColor.white.cgColor
    let path2 = UIBezierPath()
    path2.move(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 50)) 

    path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 320, y: 50)) 

    //thickHorizontalLayer.frame           = frame
    thickHorizontalLayer.path            = path2.cgPath
    thickHorizontalLayer.strokeColor     = strokeColor
    thickHorizontalLayer.lineWidth       = 20
    thickHorizontalLayer.fillColor       = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    thickHorizontalLayer.lineDashPattern = [ 1, 73.5 ]
    //thickHorizontalLayer.lineDashPhase   = 0.25

    self.layer.addSublayer(thickHorizontalLayer)

    let path3 = UIBezierPath()
    path3.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 52.5)) 
    path3.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 340.0, y: 52.5)) 


    //thinHorizontalLayer.frame            = frame
    thinHorizontalLayer.path             = path3.cgPath
    thinHorizontalLayer.strokeColor      = strokeColor
    thinHorizontalLayer.lineWidth        = 15.0
    thinHorizontalLayer.fillColor        = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    thinHorizontalLayer.lineDashPattern  = [ 0.5, 6.25 ]
    //thinHorizontalLayer.lineDashPhase    = 0.25

    self.layer.addSublayer(thinHorizontalLayer)
```

Its drawing this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0AbL.jpg

If look closely, can be seen that it's getting weird (see the color of the dashes)... : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dF0Q.jpg

I'm trying to draw 5 dashes from x:20 to x:320, and between them (but stating at x:0 to x:340) draw 9 thinner dashes. Hope someone help me with this...

Comment: You're explicitly asking for the dash phase to start halfway into the first dash.

Comment: @Ssswift I'm not using DashPhase anymore, but I'm still very confused with all this. I'm trying to draw 2 dash patterns, one thin and other thick... I will edit the question to show more.

Comment: If you want 10 times as many thin ticks as thick ticks, then those dashes should cover 1/10th the distance, no?  But 6.75 is not any integer multiple of 74.5.

Comment: @Ssswift I just don't understand the pattern that it follows. I just hard code the values until it gets what I want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this question with this: [How to make universal round draws (with lineDashPattern) with UIbezierPath on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955514/how-to-make-universal-round-draws-with-linedashpattern-with-uibezierpath-on-sw)

```
    public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height)

        var radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height+50)

        // Define the thickness of the arc.
        let arcWidth: CGFloat = 1

        let startAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI) // π
        let endAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(2 * M_PI) // π

        let counterColor = UIColor.red

        var path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                                radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2,
                                startAngle: startAngle,
                                endAngle: endAngle,
                                clockwise: true)

        path.lineWidth = arcWidth
        counterColor.setStroke()
        path.stroke()


        // init vars for later use
        var nTicks = 0
        var tickWidth = 0.0
        var gapWidth = 0.0


        radius += 20

        path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                            radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2,
                            startAngle: startAngle,
                            endAngle: endAngle,
                            clockwise: true)

        let strokeColor            = UIColor.black.cgColor

        let roundThinLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        // number of short ticks to draw
        nTicks = 150

        // thickness of short ticks
        tickWidth = 0.5

        // calculate the gap between ticks
        gapWidth = ((M_PI * Double(radius) / 2) - (tickWidth * Double(nTicks))) / Double(nTicks - 1)

        roundThinLayer.path             = path.cgPath
        roundThinLayer.strokeColor      = strokeColor
        roundThinLayer.lineWidth        = 20.0
        roundThinLayer.fillColor        = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        roundThinLayer.lineDashPattern  = [ tickWidth as NSNumber, gapWidth as NSNumber ]
        roundThinLayer.lineDashPhase    = CGFloat(tickWidth / Double(2))


        self.layer.addSublayer(roundThinLayer)


        radius += 20

        path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                            radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2,
                            startAngle: startAngle,
                            endAngle: endAngle,
                            clockwise: true)

        let roundThickLayer = CAShapeLayer()


        // number of tall ticks to draw
        nTicks = 7

        // thickness of tall ticks
        tickWidth = 1.5

        // calculate the gap between ticks
        gapWidth = ((M_PI * Double(radius) / 2) - (tickWidth * Double(nTicks))) / Double(nTicks - 1)

        roundThickLayer.path            = path.cgPath
        roundThickLayer.strokeColor     = strokeColor
        roundThickLayer.lineWidth       = 40
        roundThickLayer.fillColor       = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        roundThickLayer.lineDashPattern = [ tickWidth as NSNumber, gapWidth as NSNumber ]
        roundThickLayer.lineDashPhase   = CGFloat(tickWidth / Double(2))
        self.layer.addSublayer(roundThickLayer)

        self.clipsToBounds = true


    }
```