# How to make universal round draws (with lineDashPattern) with UIbezierPath on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I'm about to make a universal Tuner app but when I try to draw an Analog meter it gets messed on different devices. Maybe it's very hardcoded.. Check this:

[image]

The labels are under the same UIView too. Check the code to draw these paths:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height)

    var radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height+50)

    // Define the thickness of the arc.
    let arcWidth: CGFloat = 1

    let startAngle: CGFloat = π
    let endAngle: CGFloat = 2 * π

    var path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                            radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2,
                            startAngle: startAngle,
                            endAngle: endAngle,
                            clockwise: true)

    path.lineWidth = arcWidth
    counterColor.setStroke()
    path.stroke()

    radius = max(bounds.width, bounds.height+70)

    path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                            radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2,
                            startAngle: startAngle,
                            endAngle: endAngle,
                            clockwise: true)

    let strokeColor            = UIColor.black.cgColor


    roundThinLayer.path             = path.cgPath
    roundThinLayer.strokeColor      = strokeColor
    roundThinLayer.lineWidth        = 16.0
    roundThinLayer.fillColor        = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    roundThinLayer.lineDashPattern  = [ 0.5, 4.55 ]
    //roundThinLayer.lineDashPhase    = 0.25

    self.layer.addSublayer(roundThinLayer)

    radius = max(bounds.width, bounds.height+90)

    path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                        radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2,
                        startAngle: startAngle,
                        endAngle: endAngle,
                        clockwise: true)

    roundThickLayer.path            = path.cgPath
    roundThickLayer.strokeColor     = strokeColor
    roundThickLayer.lineWidth       = 40
    roundThickLayer.fillColor       = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    roundThickLayer.lineDashPattern = [ 1.5, 140 ]
    roundThickLayer.lineDashPhase   = 0.25
    self.layer.addSublayer(roundThickLayer)
}
```

Can someone help me get these values without hardcoding? i.e. I want to make the thins/thicks dashes as in the storyboard (that's running on an iPhone 7). I want to make this app universal.

Note: The autoresizing is correctly, right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Crikey @Denis, that's some old school equal sign alignment!

Comment: What is the problem? The screenshot you show there looks fine.

Comment: @AshleyMills if you look closely on emulator (as the width/height of the UIView changed) it's different compared to the storyboard. I want to know why as I set the view to autoresize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Denis - yeah, I think your hard-coded values are hurting you, particularly for the lineDashPattern.

Give this a try. It uses the length of the line (arc) and the number of ticks to calculate the "gaps" for the lineDashPattern (will likely need some tweaking for bounds and what-not)).

```
public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height)

    var radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height+50)

    // Define the thickness of the arc.
    let arcWidth: CGFloat = 1

    let startAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI) // π
    let endAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(2 * M_PI) // π

    let counterColor = UIColor.red

    var path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                            radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2,
                            startAngle: startAngle,
                            endAngle: endAngle,
                            clockwise: true)

    path.lineWidth = arcWidth
    counterColor.setStroke()
    path.stroke()


    // init vars for later use
    var nTicks = 0
    var tickWidth = 0.0
    var gapWidth = 0.0


    radius += 20

    path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                        radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2,
                        startAngle: startAngle,
                        endAngle: endAngle,
                        clockwise: true)

    let strokeColor            = UIColor.black.cgColor

    let roundThinLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    // number of short ticks to draw
    nTicks = 150

    // thickness of short ticks
    tickWidth = 0.5

    // calculate the gap between ticks
    gapWidth = ((M_PI * Double(radius) / 2) - (tickWidth * Double(nTicks))) / Double(nTicks - 1)

    roundThinLayer.path             = path.cgPath
    roundThinLayer.strokeColor      = strokeColor
    roundThinLayer.lineWidth        = 20.0
    roundThinLayer.fillColor        = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    roundThinLayer.lineDashPattern  = [ tickWidth as NSNumber, gapWidth as NSNumber ]
    roundThinLayer.lineDashPhase    = CGFloat(tickWidth / Double(2))


    self.layer.addSublayer(roundThinLayer)


    radius += 20

    path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                        radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2,
                        startAngle: startAngle,
                        endAngle: endAngle,
                        clockwise: true)

    let roundThickLayer = CAShapeLayer()


    // number of tall ticks to draw
    nTicks = 7

    // thickness of tall ticks
    tickWidth = 1.5

    // calculate the gap between ticks
    gapWidth = ((M_PI * Double(radius) / 2) - (tickWidth * Double(nTicks))) / Double(nTicks - 1)

    roundThickLayer.path            = path.cgPath
    roundThickLayer.strokeColor     = strokeColor
    roundThickLayer.lineWidth       = 40
    roundThickLayer.fillColor       = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    roundThickLayer.lineDashPattern = [ tickWidth as NSNumber, gapWidth as NSNumber ]
    roundThickLayer.lineDashPhase   = CGFloat(tickWidth / Double(2))
    self.layer.addSublayer(roundThickLayer)

    self.clipsToBounds = true


}
```

Comment: Thanks Mag. I used nTicks = 151 for thin dashes and it fitted perfectly.